# How to add +91 before mobile number in edit text in android?

Tags: android

I have an activity that contain edit text in I want to add +91 before mobile number ,Right now problem is that when I start entering mobile number like 9888888
when I enter 9 +91 is visible and after that 888888.It skip 9 first time...how can I resolve this Issue.

code:-

```
TextWatcher m_MobileWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        if (!s.toString().contains("+91")) {
            m_InputMobie.setText("+91");
            Selection.setSelection(m_InputMobie.getText(), m_InputMobie.getText().length());
        }
    }
};
m_InputMobie = (EditText) m_Main.findViewById(R.id.input_Number);
    m_InputMobie.addTextChangedListener(m_MobileWatcher);
```

Comment: m_InputMobie.setText("+91" + s);

Comment: share your xml please.

Comment: you want show +91 when users types in?

Answer (score 3):

With the `TextInputLayout` provided in the Material Components Library you can use the attrs:  **`app:prefixText="+91"`**

```
 <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/til_mobileNumber"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:prefixText="+91"
            >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/mobile_no"
                style="@style/PrimaryEditText"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="phone"
                android:maxLength="10"
                android:text=""
                android:textColor="@color/black">

                <requestFocus />

            </EditText>
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here, try making some changes to your `activity.xml` file.

```
<FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="520dp">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/mobile_no"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="0000000000"
                android:inputType="phone"
                android:maxLength="10"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                android:paddingStart="48dp"
                android:paddingEnd="8dp"
                android:paddingTop="8dp" >
                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/prefix"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:paddingStart="8dp"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:text="+91" />
        </FrameLayout>
```

Result will looks something like this:- https://i.stack.imgur.com/2guni.png

And oh! Yes! No need of any other coding.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Country code Library to give user freedom to select their countries, it also has some methods by which it can automatically select your current country and the country code will directly be assigned based on that so user don't have to select their country as well.

Take a look at this country code picker library ->

[Country code picker Library](https://github.com/hbb20/CountryCodePickerProject)

Answer (score 0):

More easier way will be to add a textview with code as text as a prefix and put some elevation. This way, you will much finer control over the designing of the code("+91"). Here's an example of the same.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 

    android:id="@+id/mobile_bottom_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/card_with_top_radius"
    android:elevation="12dp"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/dim_18"
    app:flow_verticalAlign="bottom"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

   
      
    
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/code"
        style="@style/color_333333_text_14_roboto_regular_venus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dim_16"
        android:text="+91"
        android:elevation="1dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/number"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/number"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/number" />


    <com.gradeup.baseM.view.custom.TabletEditText
        android:id="@+id/number"
        style="@style/color_333333_text_12_roboto_medium_venus"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/dim_16"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dim_17"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dim_16"
        android:background="@drawable/e6e6e6_4dp_curved_border_white_bg"
        android:hint="@string/enter_mobile_number"
        android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:maxLength="10"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:paddingVertical="@dimen/dim_17"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/dim_50"
        android:paddingEnd="20dp"
        android:textColorHint="@color/color_999999_8799ae"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/subTitle">

   

    </com.gradeup.baseM.view.custom.TabletEditText>


    

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Things to keep in mind :-

- Adjust editText paddingStart attribute according to your need.
- Put some elevation in code TextView.

Answer (score -1):

you are missing this line 
 m_InputMobie.setText("+91" + s.toString());

You have to add the character typed by user to the edit text text.

```
TextWatcher m_MobileWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                if (!s.toString().contains("+91")) {
                    m_InputMobie.setText("+91" + s.toString());
                    Selection.setSelection(m_InputMobie.getText(), m_InputMobie.getText().length());
                }
            }
        };
m_InputMobie = (EditText) m_Main.findViewById(R.id.input_Number);
        m_InputMobie.addTextChangedListener(m_MobileWatcher);
```

Comment: by doing this when i press "x" button in keyboard it clear mobile number except 91 but after clear mobile number when I again press "x" it add +91

Comment: You can move your code to onTextChange and put a check whether the event is because of keypress or a number is inputted by user